# Error messages generated in a table calculation prevent "good" elements of that table being accessed

Tags: warning-messages, list-manipulation

If I make a batch fitting routine, something like:

```
FitResultsData =     
Table[
             SpectrumData = Import[SpectrumList[[i]]]; 

             SpectrumFit = NonlinearModelFit[SpectrumData, Model, {a, b, c}, x];
                 aFitOut = a /. SpectrumFit["BestFitParameters"];
                 bFitOut = b /. SpectrumFit["BestFitParameters"];   
                 cFitOut = c /. SpectrumFit["BestFitParameters"];

             {i, aFitOut , bFitOut, cFitOut},
             {i, 1, Length[SpectrumList]}       
     ]
```

and a fit fails completely, e.g. I get a `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.` error or something, I find that when it comes to going on to use `FitResultsData` after all `Table[..]` has finished fitting and executing no matter which row I select for example `FitResultsData[[1]]` the error `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.` will be returned. This happens even say the original source of the error was in spectrum `i = 99`.

Is there a method of escaping such errors, such that even though one spectrum fit might be bad, it doesn't stop be accessing the 99% successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your situation in a simpler contrived example:

```
results =
 Table[
   {i, a /. NonlinearModelFit[
              {1}, If[i == 2, 1/0, 1], {a}, x
            ]["BestFitParameters"]},
   {i, 3}
 ];
```

As you can see, the code above triggers the `Power::infy` error *on purpose* for one value of the parameter ($i=2$), but works fine for the other two.

It is true that retrieving one of the successful results still triggers errors and warnings from the leftover failed one, but nevertheless the results from the successful runs are there and can be accessed:

[image: showing errors as well as correct results being retrieved]

If the errors bother you, you can turn them off using `Quiet` when accessing `results`:

[image: showing that Quiet prevents the errors from showing up]

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I too had a problem creating an example, which replicates my problem, in a way that is easy for anyone to produce. But quiet worked perfectly!!!